# Symfony - Sending Failed Messages on purpose

Tags: php, symfony, messenger, mailer, symfony-messenger

I'm currently using Messenger to send mails with Mailer through my MessageHandler.

Here's my messenger.yaml config file.

```
# config/packages/messenger.yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async: 
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                options:
                      table_name: messenger_message

            failed:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                options:
                    queue_name: failed
                    table_name: messenger_message_failed

        routing:
            App\Message\SendEmailMessage: async
```

How can I send failed messages on purpose to see if my messenger_message_failed receives the data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to configure the **failure transport** as [described in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/messenger.html#messenger-failure-transport):

```yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        failure_transport: failed
        # ...
```

Then in your *message handler*, just throw an exception:

```php
throw new \Exception('testing the failure transport');
```

The message will be retried 3 times unless you disable retries, then moved to the *failure transport*.

---

Note that when using **Symfony Mailer** you can natively send emails with **Messenger** (as [described in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/mailer.html#sending-messages-async)) by routing the message class to your transport:

```yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        # ...

        routing:
            'Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage': async
```

Comment: I added the failure_transport & the Exception in the handler

When I'm running the messenger:consume -vv command, I'm seeing the retries and the exception but the message is consumed & the messenger_message_failed table is still empty :(

Comment: @AureSanta maybe you consumed messages from the failure transport too ? You should only consume from your `async` transport by running `messenger:consume -vv async`. If that does not fix your issue, I don't know what's wrong with your current setup.

Comment: It works! The thing is the id default value was setup in the messenger_message table but not in the messenger_message_failed table, which I fixed, I works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: @AureSanta strange, but glad you made it work. You can accept my answer if you think that it helped you solve your problem.